# Android - asynctask, threads and image downloading

Tags: android, multithreading, android-asynctask

I have some issues figuring out the use of aSynctask, threads and downloading images. I've made a class that downloads image but doesn't implement any thread, asynctask or whatsoever.

At the moment i'm only using one asynctask to accomplish steps 1 and 2. This takes around 10 seconds with my tablet.

I have thought of 3 steps how the application would work/proceed.

1. Download the most important information from url, which is in JSON format and save it into sqlite database. This is the most relevant information that other steps need to have, in order to proceed. This takes around 2 seconds at most at the moment and I am saving this into database.
2. Query into my database to get more urls from the previous JSON data and download even more information from the same site (30 different URL's) and save the JSON into my database. This takes around 5 seconds at the moment within the single asynctask. I was thinking about separating this into 3(?) threads if possible.
3. Query database again to get information that step 2 provided and download approx 200 from different URLS, images that are of size ~150px and save these images to device storage. All of the previous steps have to be done before I can do the downloading. This has to be split up into multiple threads also so I can download as many images fast as possible.

I was wondering what would be the smartest way to use asynctask for this task and the separate threads. How many threads would you think that I would have to use (of course, I'll figure this out later on when I'm optimizing). Should I first use the asynctask to download step 1 and on post execute start the other threads? Should I create the other threads within this class that has nested async class.

Thanks a lot at least for reading all this and possibly for your help.

Edit: oh I'm using a service to start the asynctask.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only reason to make multiple threads downloading different images is if server would take some time to query for the image and as a result you are idling and not actively pumping data. But if it is not the case then your device is working as fast as your connection allows you. Hope it makes sense.

Comment: Thank you for your response. That actually makes sense, so I'll use one thread to handle all the image downloading. Now I just have to figure out if I should use multiple threads to complete step 2, since step one is a small task, so one thread would be fine there. Also I'm a bit puzzled whether I should start new threads within asynctask or not.

Comment: If step two needs to start after step one completes you need to start your threads inside the async otherwise it doesn't matter where.